# Calculate height of UICollectionViewCell dynamically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am having 2 labels which i need to add on each UICollectionViewCell. These 2 labels have the different text. I need to calculate the height of UICollectionViewCell depending upon these labels Height. How can i do that?

Comment: `label1.bounds.height + label2.bounds.height`

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension

```
extension UILabel {
    var size: CGFloat {
        let rect = NSString(string: self.text!).boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: self.font], context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd break that first line up into multiple lines... Also, why are you constructing an `NSString` from an `NSString`?  And finally, this might be easier if we just passed in the `label`.  From the label, we can get its `text`, `font`, and `width` properties... or perhaps make this an extension of `UILabel`.

Comment: it's working with multiples lines, sorry my mistake with the NSString constructing, i edited my answer

Comment: I know it's working multiple lines.  That's not relevant to a single point I just made.